# If Function - If nothing, don't do anything

Tags: excel, if-statement, runtime-error, vba

I have the following code to get rid of all filters applied on the worksheet without removing the filter function.

```
If ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode Then ActiveSheet.ShowAllData
```

This works perfectly if there is a filter applied, however on occasion there will be no filter applied and I will have to run this and it errors. The error code is 1004 and is - 'ShowAllData method of worksheet class failed'.

How can i make it so this doesn't happen so if there isn't a filter, it doesn't error.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ActiveSheet.ShowAllData` **does not** remove the current filter if there is one. It just "shows the data", but the filter remains in place so that you can eventually apply it again with `ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.ApplyFilter`.

Therefore if you call `ShowAllData` twice, with an existing filter that was not removed, it will error out.

If you want to remove a filter definitely, or simply make sure that there's no filter in place, better use this:

```
ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = False
```

This never errors out, whether there's a filter or not. So this is the way to *clear previous filter if there's any*. It doesn't need any checking by the way.

Answer (score 1):

Replace your line `If ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode Then ActiveSheet.ShowAllData` with simply `ClearTheFilter`.

Then after the current procedure (i.e. after the line `end sub` or `end function`) enter: -

```
Private Sub ClearTheFilter()
On error goto ErrorHandle
If ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode Then ActiveSheet.ShowAllData
ErrorHandle:
Err.Clear
End sub
```

What this is doing is isolating the line that could error, and then handling/clearing the error if it does happen.

Comment: When i run it with these changes i get error 424, object required which highlights the line `Error.Clear`